# get client IP from secondary dns server

Tags: logging, dns, forwarding, dnsmasq, coredns

I have a case

> `Client (config to point to DNS_1 server) <-> Internet <-> DNS_1 server <-> DNS_2 server <-> root DNS server`

Is there any way or solution so that when client accesses a website, I can get the client IP from **DNS_2** server? (I have control over both of these DNS servers.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't control DNS_1, no. Even with ECS at most you only get the client's subnet

Comment: Yes, I have control over both of these DNS servers, can you tell me how custom I should be to get the IP address of the client? @Martheen

Comment: Just enable the log and correlate them?

Comment: Is there a quicker and more optimized way? Since I found the dns queries very fast, synchronizing log streams would slow down the speed a lot

Comment: If DNS_1 can send the request using DoH, you can include the client's IP in X-Forwarded-For header. That's what I did for my proxy resolver so the resolved IP is local to the client instead of my proxy.

Comment: I am wondering if every client supports sending domain name resolution packets on port 443 (ie manually switching the resolution from port 53 to port 443).
Although DoH is enabled on the DNS server, does the client devices need to be supported or configured to use this feature? @Martheen

Comment: The client can send to DNS_1 whatever way they want (plain Do53, DoH, DoT, DoQ) except ODoH (which would remove their IP address). DNS_1 then simply parse the request and turn it into DoH into DNS_2. That's how https://github.com/AdguardTeam/AdGuardHome works

Comment: I have a few more questions about this DNS topic, can I contact you in a more convenient way? Slack / Twitter or Skype for example? @Martheen

Comment: It's better to post a new question so everyone can help to answer and it becomes a repository for future visitors. If it's a sensitive topic, then what you're looking for is a consultant.

Comment: Thanks, I just post it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345128/identify-device-from-public-dns-server. Hope you will take a look